# Стоит ли сейчас использовать Java Swing в новых проектах

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Коллеги, добрый день. 
Посоветуйте, стоит ли сейчас использовать Java Swing в новых проектах. Проект уже пишется, но он будет переписан в ближайшем будущем вероятно всего на JavaFX. Сейчас вообще в мире Java много изменений происходит, даже JavaFX хотят выпилить из Java SE, не ясна судьба данных технологий в будущем.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тому, кто распространяет эту байку про выпиливание JavaFX, надо в голову гвоздь забить! Сейчас идёт процесс модуляризации стандартной библиотеки. Чтобы в будущем программисты могли поставлять с приложением компактную версию  виртуальной машины с минимально необходимым набором библиотек. В рамках этого процесса JavaFX вынесли в отдельный модуль. Так же, как например JAXB - средства для работы с XML и JSON. В одной из следующих версий в отдельный модуль вынесут и Swing.

По сути вопроса: Swing вполне пригоден и достаточен для разработки программ с оконным графическим интерфейсом, поэтому нет причин бросаться переписывать существующий код на JavaFX. Но для новых проектов стоит предпочесть более современную и более функциональную библиотека JavaFX.

Comment: А у вас есть опыт работы со Swing-ом? Я хотел собрать разные мнения, особенно тех кто как-то использует Swing/JavaFX в проектах, чтобы убедится что Swing жив. При быстром поиске в поисковиках по Swing, часто пишут что Swing сильно устарел, мертв, и всё в таком духе. 
Тем не менее текущий проект имеет достаточно качественную архитектуру, Swing + Spring + JPA + MVC + Maven, и достаточно удобный способ создания GUI с помощью инструментария в Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Есть. О том, что Swing мёртв надо сообщить ребятам из JetBrains, а то они на нём пишут знаменитые на весь мир IDE и не знают.

Comment: Да, Idea и Netbeans на Swing написаны, но это уже исторические проекты, там большая кодовая база, от которой сложно и не разумно уходить. 
А может быть JavaFX, хоть и не такой молодой, но более сырой по сравнению со Swing, надо у разработчиков выяснить. 
Беспокоит то, по большей степени ситуация выхода новых ОС, новых версий JRE, и отсутствием поддержки Swing приложений. Oracle вроде планирует каждый пол года выпускать новые версии JDK, этой осенью Java 11 выйдет, а мой толстый клиент на Swing под Java 8 будет устаревать в геометрической прогрессии от новых технологий )