# На чём можно написать графический интерфейс desktop приложения на Java

Tags: java

Кроме стандартной swing, в Java ранее была библиотека JavaFX, которую убрали в последних версиях. Поэтому хотел бы спросить как сейчас создают интерфейс десктопного приложения на Java используют swing, JavaFX или что-то еще может быть новое есть? Какой способ наиболее популярный и лучший?

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит почитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858793/204271).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас идут в основном одним из двух путей:

1. Используют **JavaFx**. Это отличный фреймворк и его убрали из JavaSE не потому что он чем то плох, а потому что изменилась сама концепция JavaSE где стараются избавиться от всего что нельзя причислить к core для Java. Сейчас он живет и активно развивается, по нему очень много мануалов в интернете и он прошел проверку временем.
2. Пишут приложения под веб и с использованием веб фреймворков
   (например Spring MVC) и компилируют все это в JavaScript (гуглите
   проект **Electron**). Это ваш случай если вы например имеете хороший
   опыт при работе с веб приложениями, JS и верстке. Фактически десктоп
   в этом случае это клиент, сервер и браузер (хромиум) под одной
   оберткой. Этот метод часто критикуют в том числе за производительность,
   но тем не менее он уже очень популярен  за счет простоты и
   возможности переиспользовать свои навыки работы с вебом.

Answer (score 0):

Де факто для Java на desktop стандартом является swing.

> наиболее популярный и лучший

Я Вас разочарую. Java для Desktop решений вообще не популярен и очень давно не развивается.

На Java сейчас в основном пишут либо мобильные приложения под Android (и то здесь его уже очень сильно теснит Kotlin), либо крупные энтерпрайз системы для таких же крупных корпораций, которые работают на серверах и им GUI как таковой даже не нужен. Для пользователя делают отдельное приложение (как правило с web интерфейсом), но основная часть функционала всё равно скрыта под капотом серверной части.

Comment: Про де-факто я бы поспорил. JavaFX цветёт и пахнет, куча кастомных контролов. Я пока сам не окунулся в мир разработки десктопных приложений на Java, тоже думал, что всё плохо, и ничего не развивается. Но беглый гуглёж и поиск ответов на вопросы, да и потом практическое написание приложения показали, что я ошибался. Про популярность соглашусь с Вами, но тут скорее в принципе общий запрос на desktop приложения влияет. Если случится что-то такое, что сделает desktop приложения востребованнеемобильных или web-приложений, тогда и на Java будут писать много их.

Comment: Про то что пишут на Java Я в курсе. Мне интересно было мнение для десктопа что популярнее в Java для написания интерфейса. JavaFX отличный фреймворк и как по мне удобный.

Comment: Я не спорю, что Java FX хорош. Просто в вакансиях практически везде пишут swing. В прочем, смотря для чего Вы изучаете тот или иной фреймворк... Для себя можно изучать всё, что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

1) AWT - уже объявлен умершим

2) Swing уходит в прошлое. К сожалению, Swing так и не выдержал проверку временем. Правда, есть огромное количество софта написанного на Swing, так что умрет он не скоро.

3) На сцену вступает (именно так, только-только вступает) JavaFX

4) [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) - IBM'овская либа (опенсорсная). Хороша. Весь Eclipse написан на ней, да и еще много разного софта (например Vuze/Azureus написан на нем) - основное преимущество, что виджеты реализованы на C++ - посему работает быстро (очень быстро).

По сухому остатку, рекомендовал бы писать строго на JavaFX, ну если требуется быстрый интерфейс, то на SWT. Если присоединяетесь к существующему Swing проекту, то придется учить Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Все тут нахваливают FX, в принципе там всё супер, в купе с "сцен билдером". Но когда дело доходит до многопоточки... без бутылки не разберешься.

Comment: по факту все одно и то же без разницы какой UI фреймворк